# NextJS 14 Is there a better way to do this

Tags: next.js, app-router

https://github.com/Michael-Hutchinson/your-life-in-text

I currently getUserInfo from mongoDB and I want to use this information in my Sidebar but can't figure out a good way to do it.

Currently I create a prop in PageWrapper.tsx and pass it down to SidebarWrapper then to Sidebar and to get the user info I need call it on any page I want to use it e.g. I call it in my route loggedin/welcome.

I feel like theres a better way but i'm just missing it because when the app grows I will need to keep adding it to every page as I want the information to display on the sidebar

I want to try and find a better solution